# If the median of the set of data: $10;12;a;3;6;5$ is $Me=7$, what is $a$?

Tags: statistics

If the median of the following set of data: $$10;12;a;3;6;5$$
is $Me=7$, what is the value of $a$?

The set is of an even number of observations ($n=6$), so it has no distinct middle value and the median is defined to be the mean of the two middle values. We are supposed to list the numbers in order from smallest to greatest. But we don't know where the position of $a$ is... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try each position

Answer (score 1):

Half of the numbers are below the median and half above, i.e., if median is $7$ then $3, 5, 6$ are below, and $12$, $10$ and $a$ are above, so if $7$ is the mean of the two middle values, we can construct the following equation
$$
(a + 6)/2 = 7 \to a = 8
$$

Comment: I didn't get that. Three numbers are below $7$ (precisely $3,5,6$) and $2$ numbers are above it ($12$ and $10$). So "half of the numbers are below the median and half above" doesn't hold.

Comment: It does, since $a=8$, hence $8, 10, 12$ above, and $3, 5, 6$ below

Comment: I've slightly edited the statement to include $a$

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Joe said, the most clear way to answer this problem is to enumerate all the possible **ordered** sets containing the data you have and then make observations **based on** the position of $a$ in those sets :
$$
\begin{array}\{
\{a, 3, 5, 6, 10, 12\} &\implies a ≤ 3 &\implies Me=5.5 \\
\{3, a, 5, 6, 10, 12\} &\implies a ∈ \{3, 4, 5\} &\implies Me=5.5 \\ 
\{3, 5, a, 6, 10, 12\} &\implies a ∈ \{5, 6\} &\implies Me ∈ \{5.5, 6\}\\ 
\{3, 5, 6, a, 10, 12\} &\implies a ∈ \{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} &\implies Me ∈ \{6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8\} \ \star\star \\ 
\{3, 5, 6, 10, a, 12\} &\implies a ∈ \{10, 11, 12\} &\implies Me=8 \\
\{3, 5, 6, 10, 12, a\} &\implies a ≥ 12 &\implies Me=8 \\
\end{array}
$$

Here, because we are **given** that $Me=7$, we know $a$ must be in the 4th position of the ordered set (or else we have a contradiction). Equivalently, that means we must find an $a$ to satisfy $ \left(\frac{a+6}{2}=7\right)$ giving us
$$
a = 8
$$
Of course, if the set you had were really large, listing out all the possible ordered sets is a waste of time. Realize, instead, that $a$ must be in the 3rd or 4th position to affect the median (by definition of the median), and check those ordered sets instead :)